# How can I access serializer's field data before its type validation?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

How to access the field value before serialization in my serializer (`serializers.Serializer`) or rest view (`UpdateAPIView`)?

I have something like this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    my_field = serializers.IntegerField()
```

If I try to fill my field with 'test' string, it will immediately raise the ValidationError telling me about wrong data type (expecting an integer number of course). Before that error raise, I want to capture the value and do something with it but I have no idea how and where can I access it. It has an empty string value everywhere. I tried to get it in `is_valid()` before call `super()` or with `raise_exception=False`, but I still can not see it:

```
 '_kwargs': {'context': {'format': None,
                         'request': <rest_framework.request.Request object>,
                         'view': <rest.views.MyUpdateAPIView object>},
             'data': <QueryDict: {'my_field': ['']}>,
'initial_data': <QueryDict: {'my_field': ['']}>,
```

When I try to find it in my view I can also see nothing:

```
serializer.initial_data
<QueryDict: {'my_field': ['']}>

request.data
<QueryDict: {'my_field': ['']}>
```

When I try to check `validate()` or `validate_my_field()` methods, I can not even get there because of the ValidationError I mentioned above.

How the serializer validation actually works? What is the order in it and how can I access data before it is "cleaned"?

Comment: Your **`request.data`** is empty. How can we expect the data in serializer when it is empty in the request?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu yes, it is empty and that's one of the problems. The field type validation still process anyway and I get a ValidationError.

Comment: So, what all validations are you intended to do over `my_field`? Would it be empty?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.to_internal_value()` method to get the data.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior

Code exmaple:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    ret = super().to_representation(instance)
    print(ret['my_field'])
    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access the data you need to get it from the request. Data sent to the api backend can be accessed in the `request` object.

Example in your view

```
class MyFieldView(APIView):

     def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         test_string = request.data['test'] # the name of the item sent to the api
         serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
         ....
```

so what you need is `request.data`

Comment: There is nothing in `request.data`. It is empty. I use the UpdateAPIView and in my update() method the request.data looks like in my question: `request.data` returns  `< QueryDict: {'my_field': ['']} >`

Answer (score 0):

You can override de **init** method of the serializer and change de data object.

```py
    def __init__(self, instance=None, data=empty, **kwargs):
        self.instance = instance
        if data is not empty:
            self.initial_data = data
        self.partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        self._context = kwargs.pop('context', {})
        kwargs.pop('many', None)
        super(BaseSerializer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: you can use this to read de code to understand how the serializer work http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.serializers/Serializer.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried extending error handler?
have a look at this:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/

you can get the data and, for example, log it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned about that field you should try a specific field validator and have it return what you want as it raises the error.

```py
    def validate_my_field(self, value) -> int:
        if type(value) is int:
            return value
        raise ValidationError(f"The field entry {value} was not of type int but was {type(value)}")
```